# Spontaneous change of IP address

Tags: ip

I desktop computer with wired internet connection. IP is static, defined in /etc/network/interfaces. However once in a while I observe that my IP has changed without any reboot. Is there a way to find out which process changes it?
Thank you.

UPD: version of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is it? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsb_release -d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your ip isn't changing, you just have more than 1 ip.

You could have 2 ip addresses because you have 2 nicks or you're running a vpn.  `hostname -I` will list all the ip addresses you have - minus `127.0.0.1`.  `ifconfig` will list all your interfaces.  From there you can determine if it's a vpn, wifi or wired nick.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. This indeed shows 2 ip addresses. Now I need to find out where the second one comes from...

Comment: To clarify it's ok to always have 127.0.0.1 :)  - Figured I'd mention that for any newbies in the crowd.